# Datagrid is slow

Tags: c#, performance, silverlight, datagrid

I'm useing a DataGrid with has 2000+ records at the moment. The language this is written in is Silverlight 4. This amount is only going to grow in the future (with about 50 records each day). At the beginning (500- records) we had no problems with the speed. However at this point the system is getting realy slow. As soon as the page is loaded it takes about 5 minutes for all the records to be loaded and showed in the DataGrid. For this system 5 minutes really is way to long.
I heard some things about useing a DataPager and I would like to know if that is going to help improving the speed. And if anybody has some other ideas I can use to improve the speed of the DataGrid.
I included a picture of the datagrid:
[image: DataGrid]

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I included the DataPager, does somebody has more ideas?
The DataPager made some great improvements, if however you have more ideas that could work improving the speed those are more as welcome!

The problem is the data has to go through Citrix, this means the data has to go over a 5 mbit line to another country.

Comment: First thing you're going to want to look at and utilize is Virtualization and Recycling. There's multiple articles about them out there like [this one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mcsuksoldev/archive/2010/04/13/performance-characteristics-of-the-silverlight-datagrid.aspx) to get you started. Then there's also the paging which would help also. You'll see a drastic increase in performance after that.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I'm going to have a look at it today.

Comment: I just included the DataPager. Still have to look at the Virtualization and Recycling I think that needs some more research.

Comment: I don't really understand the Virtualization and Recycling part. Is there a way you could explain it to me or do you have any other tutorials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of a DataPager should have a good performance upgrade. Hope this helps you!